# DIV element aligns itself below the rest of the div elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an element inside of a div but the element doesn't horizontally align with the rest of the contents inside of the div.

Here's a picture describing my problem:
[here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFdVG.png)

As you can see the logo [M-WAY RECORDS] is not on the same row as the rest of the navbar buttons even though its in the same DIV. How do I horizontally align it with the rest of the content of the div. Keep in mind that I am a beginner coder so no need to be mean or such in comments. I'd like constructive critizism to evolve bu no need to hate on the code or me just because I made mistakes.

Anyways here's the html:

```css
body {
    font-family: SF0001;
}
/*FONTS*/
@font-face {
    font-family: SF0001;
    src: url(font/SFProDisplay-Light.ttf);
  }
/*HEADER NAVBAR*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  li a:active {
    color:rgb(41, 41, 41);
  }

  li img {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 7.5%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script link="script.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <!--Here's the image:-->
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="content/logowide.png" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any other CSS code that we are missing? And how big is the logo image shown in the picture(dimensions). I've put the provided code into a snippet and it seems to work just fine. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otLfmvac/)

Comment: It might be because your original image is big and you are scaling it in css `li img { width: 7.5%; height: 7.5%; }` which will scale the image but still keeps it in a new row as if it was big. Try and resize your original image using any photo editor then add it instead of using `width: 7.5%`.

Comment: If you want logo on top right then add ` li:last-child {float: right;}` at the end of style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of float i would just use display:flex; on li element and it's child

JSfiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/c34xzhqj/)

Code example:

```css
/*BODY*/

body {
  font-family: SF0001;
}


/*FONTS*/

@font-face {
  font-family: SF0001;
  src: url(font/SFProDisplay-Light.ttf);
}


/*HEADER NAVBAR*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 40%;
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 4%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

li a:active {
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script link="script.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">Contact</a></li>
        <!--Here's the image:-->
        <li>
          <a href="index.html"><img src="https://mlzsmzfeleix.i.optimole.com/EL7c_sg.k03b~5e599/w:auto/h:auto/q:75/https://rdlcom.com/wp-content/uploads/qa-testing-as-a-service-test-io-creative-company-logo-terrific-1.png">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you'll try to use display: inline-block; for li element ?

```
li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If you use bootstrap please let me know what version do you use.

Comment: It didn't really do anything. The logo is still on the row below.

Comment: @beginnercoder Do you use bootstrap? If so, what version ?

Answer (score 0):

So as i undustud u want to have navigation in left side, logo at midle, to do this **float** is not best solution, because u will have lot of limitation, u will have only two posibility to move left or right, and put on center only with margin.
I use **flex-box**, and this code are very simplifi your job.
U can use my example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.box:first-child>span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box:last-child>span {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* non-essential */
.box {
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  li a:active {
    color:rgb(41, 41, 41);
  }

.header-logo{
    height: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script link="script.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="box">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="pages/index-about.html">Contact</a></li>
              <!--Here's the image:-->

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="box"><a href="index.html"><img class="header-logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/Logo%21_Logo.svg/1200px-Logo%21_Logo.svg.png" /></a></div>

        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```